# Console monitor on different wifi network

Tags: arduino-yun

I have a Yun doing data logging. It runs nicely and when I am on the same wifi network I can use the Console Monitor to watch what it is doing in more detail. However, my arduino is deployed far from me so it generally isn't possible to get on the same wifi network to monitor the console.

Is there a way to monitor the console from a different wifi network?

Answer (score 1):

The Yun is just an ordinary network device.  However, the tools you are provided with use a system called mDNS to find the Yun.  That only works across the same local subnet that you are on.

If the Yun is on a different subnet then you will have to (assuming the routing between subnets is working fine) do it manually by knowing the IP address of your Yun.  Use that IP address in place of "arduino.local" or whatever your Yun is called.

Comment: Please note that you will have to port forward on your router/firewall, although that is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: So if I would be starting with googling "IP address lookup" and "router port forwarding", the answer is probably that it would take more than a few hours to set up?

Comment: If you have to google those terms, then yes, probably.  If you know what they are and how to configure your router(s) then it won't take long.  If the two network segments are isolated by NAT then you will need some form of tunnelling mechanism to get from one segment to the other, such as port forwarding (and connect to the router not the Yun) or a VPN.